# How to increase session time for phpPgAdmin in ubuntu?

Tags: phppgadmin

How to increase session time for postgres phpPgAdmin in Ubuntu ? After some time session get timeout.And each time I have to login.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar there's not anything really google-able for this matter and I personally find "I tried to find X but couldn't find it" pretty redundant, Q is about unability to find a setting, not about algorithmization.

Comment: Real annoying issue. Did you fix it?